# WSO2 ESB custom response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I set custom response in **WSO2 ESB** and i got response like

```
 {"Response":{"Status Code":"401","Status Message":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}}
```

But i want to remove **Response** node from the response.

Comment: Are you using the json contentype? What message builder and formatter you are using? Mostly this may occur when you set the response as json  and convert back and forth to xml and json. Because when you set the body as {"Status Code":"401","Status Message":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."} and convert to xml there is no root element so it attaches response as root element.

Comment: i am using json message builder

Comment: No i asked which specific json builder. If you are using org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBuilder/Formatter you do not get the on demand XML tree building for the json payload ie internally json message is maintained as xml, but in the case of org.apache.axis2.json.JSONStreamBuilder/Formatter the message is maintained as json internally as well.

Comment: tested with booth builder.

Comment: FYI, The message builders and formatters are axis2 level settings, which describe how messages are decoded (built) by the engine and encoded (formatted) for the receiver.  These properties are set in the <product home>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK ,It is not possible to remove 'Response' .Reason is same as mentioned in the comment that  Because when you set the body as {"Status Code":"401","Status Message":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."} and convert to xml there is no root element so it attaches response as root element